# ODE Linear Time Varying solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I cannot find the solution for the ODE $\dot{x} = t A x$ . Could you help me to solve it in a closed form? I thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: change of variables $s = t^2$.

Comment: I don't know what an EDO would be (except the capital of Japan, centuries ago); usually ODE is shorthand. I also don't know what LTV means. They are saying Edo was renamed Tokyo...

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix? Is it a constant?

Comment: It is a constant matrix.

Comment: suggest you solve, in detail, with $$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 7&1 \\ 0&7  \end{array} \right)  $$